# How do I find a specific word in elements in a list (python)

Tags: python, list

If I have a list `['cat', 'dog', 'cat12', 'catcat']`
and I want to search for everything which contains `'cat'` not just specifically `'cat'` how would I do that.

I.e. it would display `'cat','cat12', 'catcat'`.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?  You can test for substrings using `in`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
a = ['cat','dog', 'cat12', 'catcat']
print([x for x in a if 'cat' in x])
```

The following: `[x for x in a if 'cat' in x]` is called [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) (in one sentence: generating a new list from an existing one).

**OUTPUT**

```
['cat', 'cat12', 'catcat']
```

Comment: The `re` module is severely overkill for this.

Comment: @g.d.d.c you're right :) (I was playing with regex when I saw this question and decided to take it as a nice exercise)

Comment: This answer could do with explaining what a [list comprehension](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pShL9DCSIUw) is.

Answer (score 0):

```
l=["cat","dog", "cat12", "catcat"]

for w in l:
    if "cat" in w:
        print w


l=["cat","dog", "cat12", "catcat"]
cat_list=[]
for w in l:
    if "cat" in w:
        cat_list.append(w)
In [9]: cat_list
Out[9]: ['cat', 'cat12', 'catcat']
```